# Eclipse SDK Program "cl" is not found in PATH error

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-construction, build

Hi I am running eclipse sdk in windows and I am trying to compile my C program.  But when I build I get the following error:

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
cl /c /EHs /MD /Zi /nologo /Fosrc\test.obj ..\src\test.c
Internal Builder: Cannot run program "cl": Launching failed
Error: Program "cl" is not found in PATH
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending the full path to cl to your PATH environment variable in windows http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html just append it by adding a semi colon followed by the path to the existing value in PATH

Comment: Just updated my answer, see above, similar procedure follows for other flavours of windows. Also recommend restarting eclipse for it to take effect

Comment: What is the path to cl? I don't know how to find this path

Comment: Wherever you installed it on your computer, do a file search for cl.exe and you should find it, if not then it hasn't been installed yet

Comment: wow, now all it says is:                                                                 **** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
cl /c /EHs /MD /Zi /nologo /Fosrc\test.obj ..\src\test.c
Build error occurred, build is stopped

Comment: What makes you think I installed cl.exe, I have no idea what it even is.  I was using eclipse in linux and decided to migrate to windows, but as soon as I even tried to run a stupid test.c program I started getting this issues

Comment: btw, i am using 64 bit windows 7 with a core i7

Comment: It's a command-line C/C++ compiler commonly found on Windows. You could try this http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp and use gcc instead instead of cl as the compiler

Comment: I had to use eclipse in Linux instead.  I never got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Project -> properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool chain editor
select the toolchain you have installed as the "current toolchain"